# Entity Framework 4 - How work around to use cast with interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I use cast in Linq to Entities?

I need something like this:

```
if (typeof(myObject) is IMyInterface)
{
  return MyObjectSet.Where(x => ((IMyInterface)x).MyProperty == 1);
}
```

If I try above code, I get an exception. It's an expected behavior of EF or it's a bug?

Comment: I'm assuming this is in some generic repository context where the generic type has not yet been defined because ObjectSet itself is generic so if the generic type is defined you shouldn't need the cast? In this case is it possible to put a constraint on the generic type ala `Repository<T> where T : IMyInterface`

Comment: Isn't possible since my generic repository should work with classes that implement my interface and with classes that doesn't implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Since your interface is not in your EDMX, the EF doesn't know how to map it in an L2E query. Hard to give a good workaround without really knowing what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: It's an multi-client database. Some data will be shared to all clients. And others will be private only for 1 client.
I'm planning to implement an interface that tell to repository that this class is private, and repository will "attach" an filter.

With this, I'll remove developer error and we'll just need to implement this interface.

Sorry my poor english.

Comment: That will be hard to do well. You may limit the results returned from your repository, but if they have navigation/association properties, a client may be able to follow them to "private" data. I don't think there's a "generic" solution to this. I think that privacy concerns need to be addressed carefully and on a case-by-case basis. Putting private data in a DB is always challenging to do well.